# Mapping linear ranks from data points in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, mapping

I have a csv loaded into rows as lists within a larger list - about 500,000 of them.  One of the items in the rows/sublists is a score.  That score is a float ranging from 0 - 1.  These scores happen to be scattered in a very uneven way, and I want to normalize their distribution.  I don't need anything tricky like a bell curve, just a ranking from 1 down to 0 with even steps, with tied scores tiered by any means (doesn't matter in large numbers). I would also love the result sorted descending by score.

Example list as starting point:

```
list1 = [
    ['item1', 0.955, 'asdcwe', 'adcwett'],
    ['item2', 0.111, 'awioe', 'ocijwe'],
    ['item3', 0.111, 'dcuwq0eu', 'a9dfuwe'],
    ['item4', 0.5, 'aosdic', '204523'],
    ['item5', 1.0, 'oooo', 'ffff'],
    ['item6', 0.112, '03423', 'aewcew']]
```

Example result:

```
sortedlist = [
    ['item5', 1.0, 'oooo', 'ffff'],
    ['item1', 0.8, 'asdcwe', 'adcwett'],
    ['item4', 0.6, 'aosdic', '204523'],
    ['item6', 0.4, '03423', 'aewcew'],
    ['item2', 0.2, 'awioe', 'ocijwe'],
    ['item3', 0.0, 'dcuwq0eu', 'a9dfuwe']]
```

(Details that don't matter to me: The min/max could be inclusive or exclusive, so the scores could have resulted in 0.143 - 0.857 in this case.  Also, if item2 and item3, tied, ended up flipped in the results, that's okay, too.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest would be to sort, then normalise:

```
step = 1.0 / (len(list1) - 1)
sortedlist = [l[:1] + [(len(list1) - i - 1) * step] + l[2:] 
             for i, l in enumerate(sorted(list1, key=lambda item: item[1], reverse=True))]
```

Demo:

```
>>> list1 = [
...     ['item1', 0.955, 'asdcwe', 'adcwett'],
...     ['item2', 0.111, 'awioe', 'ocijwe'],
...     ['item3', 0.111, 'dcuwq0eu', 'a9dfuwe'],
...     ['item4', 0.5, 'aosdic', '204523'],
...     ['item5', 1.0, 'oooo', 'ffff'],
...     ['item6', 0.112, '03423', 'aewcew']]
>>> step = 1.0 / (len(list1) - 1)
>>> sortedlist = [l[:1] + [(len(list1) - i - 1) * step] + l[2:] 
...              for i, l in enumerate(sorted(list1, key=lambda item: item[1], reverse=True))]
>>> pprint(sortedlist)
[['item5', 1.0, 'oooo', 'ffff'],
 ['item1', 0.8, 'asdcwe', 'adcwett'],
 ['item4', 0.6000000000000001, 'aosdic', '204523'],
 ['item6', 0.4, '03423', 'aewcew'],
 ['item2', 0.2, 'awioe', 'ocijwe'],
 ['item3', 0.0, 'dcuwq0eu', 'a9dfuwe']]
```